# Stata: Find out which animal crosses the border to Germany

Tags: stata

I want to find out which animal crosses the border to Germany the most in the past 10 years.
My table structure is as follows:

```
+------+----------+-------------+
| Year |  Animal  | Coming from |
+------+----------+-------------+
| 2000 | bear     | netherlands |
| 2001 | ant      | netherlands |
| 2001 | spider   | netherlands |
| 2002 | dog      | poland      |
| 2003 | dinosaur | swiss       |
| 2004 | ant      | austria     |
| 2005 | bear     | poland      |
| 2006 | ant      | austria     |
| 2007 | spider   | belgium     |
| 2007 | cat      | luxembourg  |
| 2008 | fish     | belgium     |
| 2008 | ant      | poland      |
| 2009 | dog      | poland      |
| 2010 | dog      | netherlands |
+------+----------+-------------+
```

This is just sample data: my real table is much bigger with over 7k entries.

What I do want to know is the following:

Which animal came to Germany at least once per year. Here I have dificulties to explain it. I mean if a bear comes to Germany every year, no matter from which country he came to Germany 11 years (at least once). So the bear gets an 11. Now I want to group the distinct animals so I end up with a table of 2 columns, which tells me which animal came Germany every year, which came probably just 5 years out of 11. etc.

How can I achieve this in Stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install `dataex` for a better way to give data examples for Stata questions:

```
ssc inst dataex
```

The principles of counting distinct values are discussed in [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042).

This may help:

```
clear 
input Year   str8 Animal   str11 Coming_from 
2000  bear      netherlands 
2001  ant       netherlands 
2001  spider    netherlands 
2002  dog       poland      
2003  dinosaur  swiss       
2004  ant       austria     
2005  bear      poland      
2006  ant       austria     
2007  spider    belgium     
2007  cat       luxembourg  
2008  fish      belgium     
2008  ant       poland      
2009  dog       poland      
2010  dog       netherlands 
end 

egen tag = tag(Coming_from Animal Year)
egen distinct = total(tag), by(Coming_from Year)
tabdisp Coming_from Year, c(distinct) 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |                               Year                              
Coming_from | 2000  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010
------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
    austria |                            1           1                        
    belgium |                                              1     1            
 luxembourg |                                              1                  
netherlands |    1     2                                                     1
     poland |                1                 1                 1     1      
      swiss |                      1                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

egen ndistinct = total(tag), by(Coming_from Animal) 

tabdisp Coming_from Animal, c(ndistinct) 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |                             Animal                            
Coming_from |      ant     bear      cat dinosaur      dog     fish   spider
------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
    austria |        2                                                      
    belgium |                                                     1        1
 luxembourg |                          1                                    
netherlands |        1        1                          1                 1
     poland |        1        1                          2                  
      swiss |                                   1                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```